# .eval() method does not appear in the object list of BrowserWindowProxy returned from window.open()

Tags: javascript, electron

I just want to access some element from the browser window opened by using window.open() function, but I cant because the "eval method" does not appear in the objects returned from window.open() function.

I've tried to google search to see if I could find another way to accessing the element from browser opened with window.open() function, but I couldn't find any lead to a solution. I'm stacked please help!

bellow is my code

**app.js**

````
```const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

const createWindow=()=>{
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        height:500,
        width:800,
        webPreferences:{
            nodeIntegration:true,
        }
    });
    win.loadFile("index.html");
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.on("ready",()=>{
    createWindow();
});```
````

index.html

````
```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="newWin()">Open Browser</a>
    <button onclick="methods()">Available Method</button>
    <script>
        let win;

        const newWin=()=>{
           win = window.open("https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/")
        }

        const methods=()=>{
            console.log(win);
            //win.eval("document.getElementsByClassName('h2').style.fontFamily='Comic Sans Ms'");
        }

        
    </script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: JavaScript may not access documents on other domains (mozilla.org). Also why are you using eval? It's a very problematic and wasteful method, and is rarely needed, because there are better alternatives to all uses.

Comment: Thank you so much, @RoToRa, for your cooperation. I'm developing an Electron js desktop application which will be able to highlight some context from another website, it acts like a browser, so I need to be able to read the context and highlight those I need.

Comment: @RoToRa I read this BrowserWindowPronxy Class from https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window-proxy#winevalcode; it shows that the eval(code) method could give me access to the other domain DOM element